# Magento 2 Product Listing OUT OF STOCK

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to retrieve collection of product in frontend including **OUT OF STOCK** without changing System Configuration "**Disaply OUT OF STOCK => YES**".

Is there any way programmatically to change the frontend access behaves like back-end ?

Comment: Have using magento  2.1?

Comment: @AmitBera, Yes i am using Magento 2.1

Comment: an answer is listed here, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/222246/31830