# List Out of Stock Products

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to list the name of products inside the table cataloginventory_stock_item that are out of stock. Below the code I used:

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);

$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productcollection = $productCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->joinField('stock_item',
'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', 'qty=0')
                    ->setPageSize(8)
                    ->load();

foreach ($productcollection as $product){
 echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
}
```

This code return page blank as the out of stock products are present inside the table. I tried changing a different quantity and the script returns the right list.

Just a note: These products are set out of stock automatically using a REST API call function.

Any idea?

Comment: try with `$objectManager->create()` instead of `$objectManager->get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display out of stock product list when you use "frontend" as Area Code is to go to

**Store->configuration [Catalog Tab] -> Inventory->Stock Option**

and change the value [**Display Out of Stock Products = Yes**]

this code is working on my side

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect("name");
$collection->joinField(
    'is_in_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.is_in_stock = 0 ' );

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getName()."<br>";

}
```

otherwise you need to set the area code = **adminhtml**

like this

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');


$productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect("name");
$collection->joinField(
    'is_in_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.is_in_stock = 0 ' );

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getName()."<br>";

}
```

hope this code will help you

Comment: Great mate. It works :-)